# Hydromancer's Parachute

Tags: magic, physics, water

I am a hydromancer. My magical prowess grants me two abilities:

- I can breathe underwater (magically)
- I can instantly summon a sphere of pure fresh water centered on myself that's up to 50 meters in diameter if I really go all-out (this will leave me very exhausted). Any water I summon starts with zero velocity relative to my center of gravity.

Unfortunately, I am currently falling from a great height after someone pushed me out of an airship and I don't want to die on impact. Also, unlike more skilled hydromancers, I can't control any water once I've summoned it. Right now, I'm hoping that a large sphere of water summoned around myself at the last second will act as a cushion somehow, but I'm not sure that will work...

The question:

**What strategy can I use to survive a fall of arbitrary height with my abilities?**

Comment: Can you summon in different shapes?

Comment: Isn't this about the action of a characters instead than about the rules of your world, thus story based?

Comment: @Trioxidane no, spheres centered on myself only

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica This is a physics question--im wondering if the water pressure would simply crush someone on impact

Comment: What is the surface that you are falling onto?  Can you summon smaller diameter spheres of water as you are falling before the final maximum diameter effort?  (And interesting physics question which I can't see an obvious answer to)

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 I don't know the surface I am falling onto--could be solid ground, could be an ocean. Also, yes, rapidly summoning smaller spheres is no problem

Comment: Very relevant XKCD https://what-if.xkcd.com/12/

Answer (score 9):

Encasing yourself in a large blob of water which falls with you will *totally* protect you from the impact of **falling into another body of water** (lake, ocean, whatever). This will work because your water blob will enter and penetrate the water it hits, providing a very turbulent but soft cushion to fall on. A bit like going down a waterfall, where real danger is not the distance or speed of fall but drowning at the bottom, or being flung against rocks by the currents.

You will experience a sharp spike of water pressure, uniformly applied to your exterior. The larger your blow, the higher the peak pressure of this spike will be. You only need enough water around to to dampen the initial slam of impact, so something like a 6-foot radius will be ample. You are very likely to lose consciousness, i hope you float face-up afterwards.

When **about to hit the ground**, not so much. It *will* help, a bit. But the water will splash sideways more than "up", and thus will not serve to cushion you much. Mostly, you will just be *immensely* increasing the impact damage to whatever is on the ground below you, as it gets hit by many tons of free-falling <s>anvil</s>, erm water.

If you were able to generate a bit of stationary water on the ground below, even just 6 feet or so, *and* a moving blob around yourself, that might work. But it seems out of the ability spec as described.

Answer (score 3):

**Maybe the wizard can survive, but they should continuously summon spheres of water**

Warning: you should "bend" a bit the rules about hydromancy

You said that when the sphere is summoned, it has zero velocity. It means that it will provide enough drag to slow the hydromancer down a bit. <s>It also means that, if he casts it after they have reached [the terminal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity) (about 200km/h in the air), it would have the same effect on the hydromancer that it would have if they hit a surface of water at the same speed: I don't think they would survive (even if the fact that water starts falling as soon as it is summoned could somehow reduce the effect).</s>

But if the hydromancer starts to cast spheres of water as soon as they start falling, and continues to summon them at regular speed*, they should provide them with some drag.
I'm not an expert of fluid dynamics, so I'm not 100% sure it would work (it would be interesting to calculate), but as a rule of thumb, this should slow them enough to land with some chance of survival.

A secundary problem of this approach is that as soon as the wizard lands, they would be hit by the column of water they summoned during the fall, but this water should have spread large enough in order not to be a danger.

-* This is the part where I said rules should be bent: according [to this calculator](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1231475371), in order to survive to their own spell, the wizard should summon a sphere of water every few seconds, which you said they have no energy to do... So, basically, I'm afraid there aren't many chances for your hydromancer...

EDIT

As was correctly pointed out by @cjs, the water has zero velocity relative to the wizard's center of gravity, which means that when it is summoned it is falling at the same speed as the caster. So the idea that they would be injured if they summon the sphere of water after they reach more than 100km/h of speed is simply wrong.

It still holds (as @Willk pointed out) as a mean to slow the fall of the wizard, since the sphere will soon spread and reduce its fall velocity, this way slowing even the free fall of the hydromancer.
The trick will be to continuously summon smaller spheres (2-3 meters of diameter, which the wizard should be able to summon without depleting their forces). This could slow them down, then (as already hypothesize in the question) the wizard must use the 50 meter sphere at the end to provide the last cushion.
Probably the wizard will need to calculate when to start casting the spheres: as @Willk noticed, at too high altitude the water could freeze the wizard, and it could also exhaust the wizard too soon. They should calculate how much mana they can use, and time themselves so that as soon as they have cast the last small shpere, they're near the surface enough to cast the last "big" sphere to cushion the impact with the ground.

Comment: Successive spheres was my answer so upvote.  Here is how to do it.  Summon 2 meter sphere below you.  It will immediately break up from air friction and the water blobs will slow down.  The body will plow through these and be slowed.  Repeat.  Rinse.  Successive spheres will take advantage of larger surface area to slow the hydromancer.    It could get chilly.

Comment: Your comment about "the same effect as if they hit a surface of water at the same speed" is technically correct, but there is no harm done since that speed is zero. (If the caster is moving at terminal velocity downard, the summoned water will also be moving with the caster, since it "starts with zero velocity relative to [the caster's] center of gravity," according to the question.)

Comment: @cjs You're absolutely right, I misunderstood what the zero velocity was relative to (even if the idea still holds)... I'll edit the answer accordingly

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can survive, with some luck.

The trick is summoning a *hollow* sphere. Let's say with a radius of 50cm and of a 1cm thickness (so you can comfortably crouch inside).
The volume of the sphere is $V=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 \approx 0.52m^3$, the volume of the wall is approx. $V_1=4\pi r^2\cdot h \approx 0.03m^3$, i.e. the weight of the sphere is about 30 kg.

The terminal velocity of the ball will be $v_t= \sqrt\frac{2 m g}{\rho_{air} A C} \approx 36 m\cdot s^{-1} $. C is the drag coefficient for a sphere (0.47), A is the cross section.

$36 m\cdot s^{-1}$ is very high, but it is survivable with a bit of luck, [if you happen to hit a body of water](https://www.newsweek.com/laso-schaller-dana-kunze-dave-lindsay-high-diving-cliff-jump-365349), you might even escape (too many) broken bones.

The trick is to mainain the sphere's structural integrity - fortunately, you, as a hydromancer, control [the phase of the water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice) and you summon the solid state.

Edit: Astute reader will notice that the mass $m$ in the nominator depends on $r$ squared (approximately; for walls significantly less thick than the sphere radius) and the wall thickness. The cross section $A$ depends on $r$ squared (exactly). These two cancel out, so the terminal velocity does not depend (again, approximately) on the sphere size, assuming constant wall thickness. But bigger spheres are more fragile and might just crumple under the airflow. Therefore  you want the smallest sphere posssible, with the thinniest wall possible (but the velocity is still square root of the thickness, so it is pointless to risk too much by trying to shave a few milimeters too much of the wall)

Comment: You are assuming the hydromancer stays connected in location with his sphere of water

Comment: @theonlygusti yes, he is inside, and as long as the wall holds, he remains connected (why wouldn't he?)

Comment: He will fall through the air inside of the sphere faster than the sphere will fall through the air outside

Comment: @theonlygusti The sphere is 1m (or so) in diameter... there is nowhere to fall.

Comment: I missed your last paragraph where you said the hydromancer should summon ice

Comment: Great idea +1, but one thing to consider is that the hydromancer should also be able not only to summon frozen water, but also to keep it frozen. Otherwise I fear the drag of the air could melt the ice (but of course the hydromancer could summon another sphere of ice after the first was melted)

Answer (score 2):

**You can't survive**

The water starts at a 0 speed in reference to the body, but it won't stay like that. Right after the summoning the water normal physics take hold. That means drag and deformation. That sounds promising to slow you down.

Unfortunately it is a big sphere of water. That means a lot if weight and power, pulling it down. A sphere of 50m diameter is likely to at first accelerate before too much deformation will start to spread the water and slow it down. But even if it's slowing you down, it'll not be by a lot. The terminal velocity of water is still pretty high, so at best you have the terminal velocity of the water.

But then you impact the ground. You're saying you'll summon it at the last moment, so lets say exactly 50m from the ground. Water is Unfortunately a substance that is very hard to compact. A comparison. If you pressurise a container with air, the air will pack tighter and tighter, allowing for more m3 of air inside. Water practically doesn't compact tighter and tighter, so you can't put more water inside the sphere when it's full. That is also a reason water hammers work. Drop some water directly in a controlled way and it'll smash with incredible power. A reason you often hear hard noises from pipes in old houses when starting to use water.

All this to say that you don't want to land on or in water. Jump from a diving board flat on your belly and you can feel the effects of water tension and no compression. Drop in the ocean from an airplane and the water is in a way worse than landing on concrete.

You have the advantage you don't have to overcome the surface tension, but the water will still not give away fast enough. The water will come to a sudden halt, passing the energy through the bubble. The shock will be massive and lethal. If you survive that, you're still ramming the slow to move water at high speeds at the same time, killing you as well.

A hydro parachute won't work, at least not like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a scale experiment about this by filling a pot with water and a chicken egg. Climb on some stairs, turn the pot upside down as fast as you can. You now got a wet floor that also has egg yolk spread around.

When water falls inside an atmosphere like the Earth's, the drag with air causes it to spread in droplets. If your hydromancer falls from high enough all that water will fall as rain. You can see a similar effect when you look at high waterfalls: you don't have a continuous, unbroken stream coming from above. You get a shower instead.